# How can I specify which try block to continue from?

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
while True:
                        try:
                            height_input=input(f"Please enter your height in meters : ")
                            height=float(height_input)
                            # weight_input=input(f"Please enter your weight in kilograms")
                           
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")
                            continue
                        try:
                            weight_input=input(f"Please enter your weight in kilograms")
                            weight=float(weight_input)
                        except ValueError:
                            print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")
                            continue
                                                                       
                        try:
                            bmi=weight/(height*height)
                            print(round(bmi,2))
                        finally:
                            break
```

If I encounter an error with an invalid format for the line related to the user entering weight, it asks me for the height again even though that might have been entered correctly and was part of the first try block

How do I specify that if an error is encountered in the second try block, to ask the user to input the weight again (which was part of the second try block) and not return to the user input question from the first try block? (the height)

For example **the current result:**

Question: Please Enter height

User Input: 2

Question: Please Enter Weight:

User Input: ghsdek

Error Message: "Invalid Input. Please Try Again"

Question: Please Enter height

**Expected result:**

Question: Please Enter height

User Input: 2

Question: Please Enter Weight:

User Input: ghsdek

Error Message: "Invalid Input. Please Try Again"

Question: Please Enter Weight

Comment: You are using wrong syntax. This is the right syntax `except ValueError:`

Comment: You need two separate loops (or extract the input with loop into a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the code to multiply while codes, also you need to check for height being different to 0 like below:

```
while True:
    try:
        height_input = input("Please enter your height in meters : ")
        height = float(height_input)
        if height != 0:
            break

    except Exception:
        print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")

while True:
    try:
        weight_input = input("Please enter your weight in kilograms")
        weight = float(weight_input)

        break
    except Exception:
        print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")

bmi = weight/(height*height)
print(f"Your bmi is: {round(bmi,2)}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your exception handling syntax is wrong. You want the following.

```
try:
  height_input = input(f"Please enter your height in meters : ")
  height = float(height_input)
except ValueError:
  print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")
  continue
```

Secondly, `continue` is just going to the next loop iteration. You can't tell it where in the loop to begin. What you need are three *separate* loops to read each piece of information.

Thirdly, at the end of each try block you'll want to `break` or your loops will continue infinitely.

Comment: Thank you.! I am currently still learning python and had the continue was a way for it to return to the start of the loop

Answer (score 1):

I'd extract the input logic into a function in accordance with the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. That would also make the code more readable:

```
def input_value(msg, type):
    while True:
        try:
            return type(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input. Please Try Again")

weight = input_value("Please enter your weight in kilograms: ", float)
height = input_value("Please enter your height in meters: ", float)
```